# How to display user infos after authorization?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to make a profile component on my Angular app. After user Successfully login or sign up, I want to display user profil picture, name, and email in profile component but I don't know how.

Comment: What did you try to do? what works, or even more important, what doesn't?

Answer (score 4):

Hope you have create Webapi for auth and have setup Database.

After you authenticate the user you can redirect to the User Dashboard page (in your case the profile pic , name ,etc) via Webapi. Refer - [Redirecting User after Auth](https://youtube.com/watch?v=-asykt9Zo_w)